Si quiero realizar una acción en el momento que se ingrese a la pagina, ¿qué es mejor usar, el document.ready o el document.onload?
Tengo este código en el que quiero agregarle una función a unos botones. Sé que el código no es el más óptimo, pero quisiera saber por que es diferente poner el .ready a poner .onload y por que cada uno funciona en determinados momentos y en otros no.
$(document).ready(function() {
            var formsEliminar = document.querySelectorAll('form[id^="formEliminarProducto-"]');

            formsEliminar.forEach(function(formEliminar) {
                var btnEliminarProducto = formEliminar.querySelector('.btnEliminarProducto');
                
                btnEliminarProducto.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault(); // Evita el envío del formulario por defecto
                    
                    var formulario = event.target.closest('form');
                    var id = formulario.dataset.id;
                    
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: '¿Estás seguro?',
                        text: "Esta acción no se puede revertir",
                        icon: 'warning',
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
                        cancelButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Sí, eliminar',
                        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result.isConfirmed) {
                            formulario.submit();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            document.getElementById('mostrarFormStock').addEventListener('click', function() {
                var formStock = document.getElementById('formStock');
                formStock.removeAttribute('hidden');
            });

            document.getElementById('formConfigStock').addEventListener('submit', function() {
                var formStock = document.getElementById('formStock');
                formStock.setAttribute('hidden', true);
            });
        });


window.onload es un evento que se ejecuta cuando todos los archivos han sido cargados (imágenes, css, scripts, etc.)
document.onload se ejecuta una vez el objeto DOM esta listo, esto puede suceder previo a que las imágenes y links externos se carguen
Dejar claro que document.ready no existe, a lo que te refieres es a una función de la librería jQuery la cual es la siguiente
$(document).ready la cual intenta proveer consistencia entre los dos eventos anteriores mencionados y es que los distintos navegadores los ejecutan con algunas diferencias
